# PostgreSQL Referencing

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

When I try to create the Contact table I am receiving the following error:
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "contactnumber"

I assume that this is because there is no NumberPerContact attribute in Contact table but I dont want to have one. What could I do ?

```
 CREATE TABLE ContactNumber (
        ContactID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        NumberPerContact INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ,
        ContactNumber VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '',
        PRIMARY KEY (ContactID, NumberPerContact),
        UNIQUE(CONTACTID,NUMBERPERCONTACT)
    );

CREATE TABLE Contact (
    EventName VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    ContactID INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (EventName,ContactID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ContactID) REFERENCES ContactNUMBER (CONTACTID), 
    FOREIGN KEY (CONTACTID) REFERENCES CONTACTMAIL(CONTACTID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CONTACTID) REFERENCES CONTACTNAME(CONTACTID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CONTACTID) REFERENCES ORGANIZer(CONTACTID)
    );
```

Comment: You are trying to create a foreign key constraint on the `ContactID` field, but that is not the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Your primary key is defined as `ContactID, NumberPerContact`.  You will either need to change how that's defined in the `ContactNumber` table or add `NumberPerContact` to the `Contact` table and add that to your `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.  You mention that you don't want to have one in your question, but those two fields are the *identifying fields for the record.*  If that is how you want that defined, you *have* to use both.

Comment: As an aside, the `UNIQUE` constraint on `ContactID, NumberPerContact` in addition to those two fields being defined as the `PRIMARY KEY` is redundant.  By definition, they're already unique via being the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Leaving only ContactID for a primary key in ContactNumber table allowed me to create both tables. I want both ContactID and NumberPerContact to be unique not only one of them. Removing NumberPerContact from PK failed this. UNIQUQ (atr1,atr2) doesn't work as I expected

Comment: I tested the solution of Dimitar Velikov and it is ok. Leave only ContactID for a primary key because you have an unique key(CONTACTID,NUMBERPERCONTACT)

Comment: @PlsqlTutorial
This is not a solution.

=> insert into contactnumber values (1,1,'01');
INSERT 0 1
insert into contactnumber values (1,2,'01');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "contactnumber_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (contactid)=(1) already exists.

the idea is 1,1 and 1,2 to be counted as unique - not only contactID but numberpercontact as well. Removing numberpercontact fails that even with using UNIQUE(col1, col2)

Comment: @Dimitar Velikov, you're right I tested only create table.

Comment: I feel like the solution has to be something with CONSTRAINTS but I am not sure how to use it 
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX x ON contactnumber (contactid,numberpercontact);

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key constraint must be unique in the table being referenced.

Hence

```
FOREIGN KEY (ContactID) REFERENCES ContactNUMBER (CONTACTID)
```

will only be valid if one of two is true:

1. ContactID is the primary key of ContactNumber table.

or

2. ContactID is declared UNIQUE in the ContactNumber table.

In your case, you are doing in backwards!!

the FOREIGN KEY constraint must be placed in ContactNumber, not in Contact!

```
FOREIGN KEY (ContactID) REFERENCES Contacts (CONTACTID)
```

For your example:

```
CREATE TABLE ContactNumber (
    ContactID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    NumberPerContact INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ,
    ContactNumber VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (ContactID, NumberPerContact),
    UNIQUE(CONTACTID,NUMBERPERCONTACT)
    FOREIGN KEY (ContactID) REFERENCES Contact (CONTACTID), 
);

CREATE TABLE Contact (
    EventName VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    ContactID INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (EventName,ContactID), 
);
```

Also, if ContactId is UNIQUE in Contact then it is a better candidate key than EventName, ContactID, so ContactID should be its primary key.

ContactId -> EventName

Comment: The idea of contact table is :
Event has Contact;
Contact has name,number etc.
This is why i tought that contact should reference all those tables

Comment: In the process of normalization you have to move the confilcting attributes to a new table with copy of the PK in the new table. What are you saying might work but is not right.

Comment: Referencing the tables is good practice. It is just that you did it backwards. You reference in the "child" table the "parent" table. The FOREIGN KEY constraint goes in the child table.

Comment: Thank you! You are right and I was completely wrong.